# MySQL distinct combination of values from cross reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to find an efficient way to query data a certain way. My database is a simple MySQL off an external web server I don't have complete access to, and it's accessed through a web browser. Any queries I have tried have involved extremely large query results.

General table layouts:

`Product` table with columns `{ID, Name}` (it has more columns but for the query I need they are not relevant)

`Types` table with columns `{ID, Name}`

`Crossreference` table with columns `{ProductID, TypeID}` (1 product can have many types, and 1 type can have many products)

Query results needed:

```
ProductName1, 
ProductName2, 
ProductName3, 
group_concat(TypeName), 
Count(TypeName)
with COUNT(TypeName) > 1
```

Where `typename` includes product names of the same type, and there are 2 or more matching types between each product. So `group_concat(typename)` would include matches between

- *productname1* and *productname2*,
- a different match between 
  *productname1* and *productname3*,
- a different match between *productname2* and productname3,
- and maybe a match between *productname1*, *productname2*, and *productname3* comprising of 4 distinct types.

And finally with a row output of values 'a', 'b', and 'c' for the products, with no extra outputs of  'b','c','a' or 'c', 'b', 'a', etc.

I have had better results with only 2 product columns output to a temp table, then deleting the duplicates, but I can't seem to make it efficient for 3 columns, or even have it be efficient to gather the data with just a single query and no temp table.